# Arduino stops working after several seconds

Tags: c++, arduino, pid-controller

I'm trying to build a PID controller for a Segway type vehicle.  I run the code and it will stop working after a few seconds.  I am using a sparkfun 9d0f IMU with an Arduino uno. I'm guessing there's an overflow somewhere or an endless loop. Any ideas? Could it be from polling the IMU?

```
 /******************************
 * segBoard Attitude Control 2.0
 * this is the second version of the attitude control code for the 
 * spring 2015 400d segBoard project. this code uses the sparkfun 
 * 9dof to gather data about the attitude of the board and convert 
 * it to PID for controlling the motor.
 * 
 * Written by: Antonio Cole 2/29/15
 * 
 */


#include <SPI.h> // Included for SFE_LSM9DS0 library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SFE_LSM9DS0.h>

// SDO_XM and SDO_G are both grounded, so our addresses are:
#define LSM9DS0_XM  0x1D // Would be 0x1E if SDO_XM is LOW
#define LSM9DS0_G   0x6B // Would be 0x6A if SDO_G is LOW
// Create an instance of the LSM9DS0 library called `dof` the
// parameters for this constructor are:
// [SPI or I2C Mode declaration],[gyro I2C address],[xm I2C add.]
LSM9DS0 dof(MODE_I2C, LSM9DS0_G, LSM9DS0_XM);

const int leftPin = 9;
const int rightPin  = 10;
const int samples = 60;

int pitchControl = 0;
int index = 0;
int pitch = 0;

float angle = 0;
float accelX[samples];
float accelY[samples];
float accelZ[samples];
float accelXaverage = 0;
float accelYaverage = 0;
float accelZaverage = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(leftPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200); // Start serial at 115200 bps
  // Use the begin() function to initialize the LSM9DS0 library.
  // You can either call it with no parameters (the easy way):
  uint16_t status = dof.begin();
  /*for(int i = 0; i < 6 i++){
    dof.readAccel();
  }
  delay(1);
  */
  Serial.print("LSM9DS0 WHO_AM_I's returned: 0x");
  Serial.println(status, HEX);
  Serial.println("Should be 0x49D4");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop(){
  dof.readAccel();

  accelX[index] = dof.calcAccel(dof.ax) - 0.01;
  accelY[index] = dof.calcAccel(dof.ay) - 0.01;
  accelZ[index] = dof.calcAccel(dof.az) - 0.02;

  float accelXsum = 0;
  float accelYsum = 0;
  float accelZsum = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    accelXsum = accelXsum + accelX[i];
    accelYsum = accelYsum + accelY[i];
    accelZsum = accelZsum + accelZ[i];
  }
  accelXaverage = accelXsum / samples;
  accelYaverage = accelYsum / samples;
  accelZaverage = accelZsum / samples;

  angle = atan2(accelXaverage, sqrt(accelYaverage * accelYaverage)
    + (accelZaverage * accelZaverage))*100;
  pitch = constrain(angle, -15, 15);

  if(pitch < 0){
    pitchControl = map(pitch, -15, 0, 255, 0); 
    analogWrite(rightPin, 0);
    analogWrite(leftPin, pitchControl);
  }
  else if(pitch > 0){
    pitchControl = map(pitch, 0, 15, 0, 255); 
    analogWrite(leftPin, 0);
    analogWrite(rightPin, pitchControl);
  }
  else{
    analogWrite(leftPin, 0);
    analogWrite(rightPin, 0);
  }

  Serial.print(index);
  Serial.print(";");
  Serial.println(pitchControl);

  index++;
  if(index == samples){
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about this system, you need to apply a standard debugging technique to isolate the problem.

Pull everything out so you have empty setup() and main() functions. Maybe add in the print statements. See if that works. Then keep adding code until it breaks. The last thing  added is the problem.